# Reason why $F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}$ and $\tilde{F}_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$ are Lorentz invariant

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, invariants

I'm trying to think of an intuitive reasoning for why $F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}$ and $\tilde{F}_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$ are Lorentz invariant. By this I mean that I don't simply want to show that they remain unchanged after actually performing a Lorentz transformation and seeing that I end up with the same expressions, but some sort of 'deeper' understand of why this is so. I just can't really think of why these expressions (written out in vectors like $E^2 - B^2$ and $B \cdot E$ with some constants) would be the same for every inertial observer, while for a space-time interval I can sort of grasp this.

Is there perhaps a good reference someone could point me to?

Comment: You could look up the Lorentz transformations of the $B$ and $E$ fields (12.108 in Griffiths' Intro to Electrodynamics, there's a derivation there too). Then, section 12.3.3 explains how to explicitly construct the EM field tensor and its dual. Finally, exercises 12.46 and 12.50 help develop an intuition.

Comment: While the expressions in terms of the electric and magnetic fields are not obviously Lorentz invariant, Lorentz invariance is manifest when written in terms of the Electromagnetic field strength. This is similar to why the dot product of two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are invariant under rotations. A simple search for "four-vectors" will give you the answer.

Comment: I don't know if you this is "intuitive" for you, but if you accept that F is a tensor, then obviously its contractions are scalars.

Comment: @Danu: Hm, I have to say I don't really see how those give an intuition, they seem to be show that it is true, rather than give a sort of underlying reason.

Suresh: I'm not sure I completely follow. Do you mean that the 4-vector equivalent of a dot product is invariant under Lorentz transformations?

Enucatl: I'm afraid I'm looking for a bit more than that yeah, as I know that that is true, but I am trying to understand why, in this specific case. What makes these quantities so special?

Comment: @user129412 Yes, the 4-vector equivalent of a dot product ($x_\mu y^\mu$) in Minkowski space is a scalar, just as the Euclidean dot product in $\mathbb{R}^3$ ($x_iy^i$). The fact that we can arrange non-invariant numbers into 4-vectors with an invariant 'dot product' suggests that something similar might be possible, arranging 3-component vectors into 2-tensors with an invariant 'dot product'. The specific transformation laws for $E$ and $B$ are *especially suggestive*, which is why I referred to them.

Comment: @suresh I think this is not what OP is asking. The real question would be how to make it *a priori* clear that this combination of the components of $E$ and $B$ can be arranged to form $F_{\mu\nu}$, such that we have the above-mentioned scalars.

Comment: Hm, I see. Would it be valid to say that a scalar constructed from the product of two tensors is Lorentz invariant?

Comment: @user129412 Indeed, it is. *Any* object that can be written in the form $A=t_\mu x^\mu b_{\lambda\kappa\rho}c^\kappa f^{\lambda\rho}\dots$ (i.e. a 'full contraction' of a product of tensors of arbitrary rank) is a scalar, and therefore Lorentz invariant.

Comment: Hm, your answer seems to suggest that all scalars are Lorentz invariant, but then why is there a 'special' class called Lorentz scalars? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_scalar

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13550/discussion-between-danu-and-user129412)

Comment: @user129412 all scalars constructed in the way I just outlined *are* Lorentz scalars. In everyday usage, the words scalar and Lorentz scalars are used interchangeably

Comment: What's $\tilde{F}_{\mu\nu}?$

Comment: It's the dual field tensor. The notation might be somewhat unconvential, I apologize.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/87817/2451 and links therein.

Comment: I actually know what that is, but I think you should define it here.

Comment: Eigenvalues are invariants, find the eigenvalues of $F^{\mu}_{\nu}$ by computing the characteristic equation $\det(F^{\mu}_{\nu} - \lambda \delta^{\mu}_{\nu}) = 0$, the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial spit out both expressions (and by Vieta's theorem are expressed in terms of the eigenvalues hence invariant), Dalarsson sec. 15.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're lorentz scalars.  Every scalar is lorentz invariant.

Answer (score 1):

$F_{\mu\nu}$ is a Lorentz tensor, easy to see by $\partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu$, which is a 2-form. Contractions of Lorentz tensors are Lorentz tensors. $\tilde{F} = \star F$ is the Hodge dual of $F$, which is also a 2-form, hence a Lorentz tensor, therefore the same applies about its contractions. By these definitions, they are also tensors in curved spacetime.

Comment: Of course, if you want to speak differential forms, then $F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu} = \star (F\wedge \star F)$
and $\tilde{F}_{\mu\nu} F^{\mu\nu} = \star (F \wedge F)$.
The translation between forms and index notation is not always as obvious as one would like. :)

Comment: @RobinEkman Yes, that's why I'm used to combining the two, depending on which leads to simpler expressions. For example, I've never done contractions using the Hodge dual and I prefer to replace it with the expression in terms of tensors.

Comment: Yes, they both have their merits, a physicist worth his or her salt should be comfortable with both.