# How to show invariance using the Maxwell tensor?

Tags: special-relativity, relativity, tensor-calculus, invariants

I want to show the invariance of $E^2-c^2B^2$ under the Lorentz transformations. The obvious way to do this is to show that $$E^2-c^2B^2=E'^2-c^2B'^2,$$ where $E'$ and $B'$ are the Lorentz transformations of the electric and magnetic fields, respectively. This is quite a simple yet very inelegant calculation (one applies the Lorentz transformation to each of $E_x, E_y, E_z, B_x, B_y, B_z$ and the invariance follows).

How can I do this using the Maxwell tensor? I believe that it is possible to show invariance by doing the matrix multiplication of $$F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$$ but I am unsure of how to actually do this (I am confused about what what $F_{\mu\nu}$ actually is), and I am confused how this could stretch to showing the invariance of other things, because surely this matrix multiplication would always give the same answer...

Comment: Hello. The quantity you wrote is a scalar because of contraction, so it' s Lorentz invariant, that is, it' s the same at every coordinate system by a Lorentz transformation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103167/

Comment: Can you show this mathematically? I was asked to show them mathematically - did it the first way and my lecturer said it would be easier to do $F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}$

Comment: Yes, you can. Take the rule for transforming the (2,0) and (0,2) tensor and show that the product of the two, that is the quantity you wrote, remains the same. You should show then that it transforms as a scalar.

Comment: Expand the term $F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$ to show that it is equal to $\sim (E^2-c^2B^2)$ (not sure anout the overall sign). You just have to note that $F^{0i}=-E^i$ and $F^{ij}=-\epsilon^{ijk}B^k$, and since the indices are contracted which ensures that $(E^2-c^2B^2)$ is Lorentz invariant.

Answer (score 4):

How does a scalar quantity transforms under a Lorentz transformation?

I will show you here how this works for a vector (contravariant) and a covector.

The transformation rule for these objects are

$$u^a = { \partial x^a \over \partial x' ^b} u' ^b $$

$$u_a = { \partial x'^b \over \partial x^a}u' _b $$

Multiplying the two:

$$ u^{a}  u_{a} = { \partial x^a \over \partial x'^b} {\partial x'^b \over \partial x^a} u' ^{b} u' _{b} .$$

So, by eliminating the terms that are the same we have

$$u^a u_a =u' _b u' ^b =u' ^a u' _a,$$ where we rename the indexes b to a since b is a mute index.

Since this quantity is a scalar, and thus the same in both reference frames. By taking the general transformation rule for the tensors you have you can show the same.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I believe $F^{\mu\nu}$ is better known as the Faraday tensor; Maxwell tensor is only the spatial part of it, 3x3 matrix.

The argument goes like this: $F$ is a four-tensor, so if any quantity is constructed from it by multiplication of its components, this new quantity also has to transform as a tensor. The construct
$$
F^{\mu\nu}(g_{\mu\rho}g_{\nu\sigma}F^{\rho\sigma})
$$
results in a single number. It has no index left, because there is summation over all of them.

The only way a single number could transform as a tensor is if it is the same number in all coordinate systems. Hence $F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}$ is invariant. When components of $F$ are expressed through components of $\mathbf E,\mathbf B$, it turns out this number is $2c^2(B_x^2+B_x^2+B_x^2)-2(E_x^2+E_y^2+E_z^2)$ (in SI units).