# Is the equal sharing of EM field energy between $\textbf{E}$ and $\textbf{B}$ fields a Lorentz invariant statement?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, classical-electrodynamics, maxwell-equations

My book claims that in *vacuum*, the total energy density of the electromagnetic field is *equally* shared between electric and magnetic fields by explicitly showing that $$\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_0 \textbf{E}^2=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\textbf{B}^2}{\mu_0}.$$

$\bullet$ However, one can change to a different inertial frame by a Lorentz boost where $\textbf{E}$ or $\textbf{B}$ will mix up. Is this statement a Lorentz invariant assertion? If not, does it imply we are in a special Lorentz frame (not violating relativity, of course!) in which this claim is true?

$\bullet$ Is it possible to go a frame in which one of the fields ($\textbf{E}$ or $\textbf{B}$ ) of an EM wave is made to vanish? Then it is clear that the above claim is meaningless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the question in the title is yes. There are [two fundamental Lorentz invariant scalars of the EM field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/87817/fundamental-invariants-of-the-electromagnetic-field),

$$\frac12F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}=\mathbf{B}^2-\mathbf{E}^2$$
and
$$\frac14F_{\mu\nu}\ {}^\ast F^{\mu\nu}=\frac14\epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta }F_{\mu\nu}F_{\alpha\beta}=\mathbf{B}\cdot\mathbf{E}$$

(modulo units and constants). The former reflects exactly the equal-energy-density property of electromagnetic radiation, and it guarantees that if $\mathbf B ^2 = \mathbf E^2$ in one frame, then that stays true in all frames of reference.

In general, for radiation, the equal sharing is at least morally true, and it's easy to verify for plane-wave radiation. On the other hand, there are plenty of fields for which energy is not equally shared, with the simplest example being the electrostatic field of a point charge.

Moreover, for homogeneous fields (or locally for inhomogeneous fields) any two configurations that share those two invariants are almost certainly connected by a Lorentz transformation (but check for a proof before you take my word for it).

Comment: So do you think the claim is true?

Comment: @akhmeteli See edited answer.

Comment: Neither do I think that the claim is true (please see my answer), but your example of the field of a point charge does not seem applicable as there are no charges in vacuum.

Comment: But what does it mean: "for radiation, the equal sharing is at least morally true"? I believe the claim is not true even for radiation, as the evolution of the radiation fields is described by first-order PDE, whereas $E^2-B^2=0$ is algebraic and can be violated in initial conditions.

Comment: @akhmeteli Requiring the absence of charges *everywhere* is much too strong a statement, and the only consistent field in that case is identically zero. "In vacuum" normally means a *local* vacuum, which is perfectly applicable to a point charge.

Comment: If you prefer such definition of vacuum, it's fine, but radiation does not necessarily need any charges ( a plane wave is an example).

Comment: On the radiation thing, it comes down to what you really mean by radiation. That's a pretty fuzzy concept, which means that statements about it will be fuzzy as well. For your example, I would not count all initial conditions as radiation. More to the point, take a point charge undergoing harmonic motion - how do you split the radiation and electrostatic components? How precise a statement can you make on the radiation's behaviour, given that the electrostatic field is still there?

Comment: @akhmeteli Of course radiation needs charges. Where did you get your plane wave from in the first place? Imagining the light without the lamp is nice, and it might be mathematically consistent, but it's not physical at all.

Comment: I certainly agree that charges can produce radiation, but, in my book, radiation also includes any (decent - sufficiently smooth, sufficiently normalizable) solution of free Maxwell equation in the entire spacetime. Why should a solution of the free equations with arbitrary initial conditions (with vanishing divergence) not be considered radiation?

Comment: I don't see why radiation without charges cannot be physical: for example, if an electron and positron annihilate, you have pure radiation, without charges.

Comment: I think in order to produce EM wave one must have charges. But once it is produced, you can forget all charges because the radiation is then self-sustaining. Right?

Comment: @akhmeteli That's mostly beside the point. I just want to contest the interpretation of the OP's claim of "in vacuum" as *requiring* the absence of charges everywhere. SRS's comment is correct.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty: As I said, if you prefer your definition of vacuum, it's fine with me.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty- One thing is still not clear to me. If we take a spherical wave solution of (linear) Maxwell's equation, or any other complicated solution, I can always decompose it into plane wave Fourier modes. So if this "equal sharing thing" is true for each mode, why not for arbitrary solution of Maxwell's equation?

Comment: @SRS Because the $E^2$ term includes cross terms where each mode interferes with every other mode, and you can't tell anything about their behaviour. The method simply cannot work, because it would also apply to the static field of a point charge (which is also equal to the Fourier transform of its transform).

Answer (score 1):

I strongly doubt this claim: you can choose initial fields (at some initial time point in the entire 3d space) arbitrarily (provided divergence of electric and magnetic field vanishes). The claim is true, however, for a plane (sinusoidal) electromagnetic wave, and this does not depend of the (inertial) frame of reference, as $E^2-B^2$ is a Lorentz invariant.