# Building the Lagrangian of electromagnetism from the Lorentz invariant?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, lorentz-symmetry, invariants

The definition of the relativistic Action is

$$
S=\int_a^b ds
$$

The Lorentz invariant of electromagnetism is

$$
s^2=\frac{1}{c^2}||\mathbf{E}||^2-||\mathbf{B}||^2-2i\frac{1}{c}(\mathbf{B}\cdot \mathbf{E})
$$

Therefore, could we write the action as:

$$
S=\int_a^b d\sqrt{\frac{1}{c^2}||\mathbf{E}||^2-||\mathbf{B}||^2-2i\frac{1}{c}(\mathbf{B}\cdot \mathbf{E})}
$$

This may not be the prettiest way to write it I concede, but is it possible? Clearly, this is not the field description, but perhaps the movement of a test particle/photon in an electromagnetic field?

Comment: You should probably look up the covariant notation for electromagnetism, which is written in terms of the scalar and vector potentials. It is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @FeelMyBlackHole I am familiar with the covariant notation, but what I am looking for it to know if the Lagrangian can be built from the Lorentz invariant in the manner stated in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/87817/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

Your first equation is the relativistic action for a free point particle, where $ds$ is the infinitesimal invariant arc length along its world line.

This invariant geometric spacetime interval has nothing to do with the electromagnetic field invariant $s^2$ you write in the next equation.

That electromagnetic invariant combines a scalar and a pseudoscalar so is unsuitable for an electromagnetic action.

The final equation makes no sense. The variable of integration in a normal  integral cannot itself be a function. And what are $a$ and $b$ now? Not only does it not describe the motion of either a test particle or a photons in an EM field (and, by the way, photons just go straight and don’t feel the field), there is no way that it *could* describe these things. No world line appears in this integral, nor any interaction between the field and a charged test particle.